# convert this LINQ expression into Lambda

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Guys, I have a hard time converting this below linq expression(left join implementation) to lambda expression (for learning).

```
var result = from g in grocery
       join f in fruit on g.fruitId equals f.fruitId into tempFruit
       join v in veggie on g.vegid equals v.vegid into tempVegg
       from joinedFruit in tempFruit.DefaultIfEmpty()
       from joinedVegg in tempVegg.DefaultIfEmpty()
       select new { g.fruitId, g.vegid, fname = ((joinedFruit == null) ? string.Empty :     joinedFruit.fname), vname = ((joinedVegg == null) ? string.Empty : joinedVegg.vname) };
```

Can some one suggest me how to do this.

And i really appreciate if someone give me the excellent tutorial links for **"C# Lambdas & Linqs"**

Answer (score 31):

To convert a Linq query to it's Lambda equivalent:

1. Download [Linqpad](http://www.linqpad.net/) and run your
   query.
2. In the results window, click
   on the "λ" button in the toolbar.
   It's right above the Results window
3. Your query will be converted to a
   Lambda expression equivalent!

[image]

Comment: I have Linqpad but without creating a 'connection' to a service that I can query, I can not see the button for the lambda. I do not know how to just paste in a LINQ query and convert it to a lambda. Is this actually possible?

Comment: I just added a pic for where the button is in the UI. I don't have Linqpad on hand, but I think you need to have a runnable query there before it can be converted to a Lambda. In another post, I detailed how you can test data in Linqpad without needing a DB, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611031/convert-json-string-to-c-sharp-object/7446542#7446542

Comment: can it convert SQL to lambda or LINQ? Doesn't seem to be working

Comment: I haven't used it in a long time, but what does clicking the `SQL` button beside the `λ` do?

Answer (score 12):

You can take a look at [101 LINQ Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746.aspx) and [C# 3.0 QUERY EXPRESSION TRANSLATION CHEAT SHEET](http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2008/08/30/c-3-0-query-expression-translation-cheat-sheet.aspx)

Comment: thanks for the links Dzmitry... the cheat sheet is useful... i already have a look at 101 samples..

Comment: hey where would i get the source code for the 101 samples.. any idea.. i couldnt find there...

Comment: @RameshVel here: https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/samples/dotnet/try-samples/101-linq-samples/

Answer (score 11):

Here's the heuristic that I follow:

> Favor LINQ expressions over lambdas when you have joins.

I think that lambdas with joins look messy and are difficult to read.

Comment: thanks jim for the reply. But i wanted to do this in lambda to get familiar with.. i mentioned that already its for learning...

Answer (score 10):

I usually use ReSharper to help me convert things to method chains and lambda's, which helps me go back and forth fairly easy.

```
    var result = from g in grocery
                 join f in fruit on g.fruitId equals f.fruitId into tempFruit
                 join v in veggie on g.vegid equals v.vegid into tempVegg
                 from joinedFruit in tempFruit.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 from joinedVegg in tempVegg.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 select new { g.fruitId, g.vegid, fname = ((joinedFruit == null) ? string.Empty : joinedFruit.fname), vname = ((joinedVegg == null) ? string.Empty : joinedVegg.vname) };
```

And then using ReSharper's option of convert LINQ to method chain equals the following:

```
        var result =grocery .GroupJoin(fruit, g => g.fruitId, f => f.fruitId, (g, tempFruit) => new {g, tempFruit})
                            .GroupJoin(veggie, @t => @t.g.vegid, v => v.vegid, (@t, tempVegg) => new {@t, tempVegg})
                            .SelectMany(@t => @t.@t.tempFruit.DefaultIfEmpty(), (@t, joinedFruit) => new {@t, joinedFruit})
                            .SelectMany(@t => @t.@t.tempVegg.DefaultIfEmpty(),(@t, joinedVegg) =>
                                new
                                    {
                                        @t.@t.@t.g.fruitId,
                                        @t.@t.@t.g.vegid,
                                        fname = ((@t.joinedFruit == null) ? string.Empty : @t.joinedFruit.fname),
                                        vname = ((joinedVegg == null) ? string.Empty : joinedVegg.vname)
                                    });
```

Granted the output is less then desirable, but It at least helps in starting somewhere on understanding the syntax.

Comment: thanks Mark for your response.. i will run it over here and will let you know if that works..

Answer (score 4):

Here’s how you might write this query in lambda:

```
var cus­tomers = new List {
new Cus­tomer { Com­pa­nyId = “AC”, Cus­tomerId = “Customer1” },
new Cus­tomer { Com­pa­nyId = “not-AC”, Cus­tomerId = “Customer2” },
};

var user­Cus­tomers = new List {
new User­Cus­tomer { Com­pa­nyId = “AC”, Cus­tomerId = “Customer1”, User = “not-admin” },
new User­Cus­tomer { Com­pa­nyId = “AC”, Cus­tomerId = “Customer1”, User = “admin” },
new User­Cus­tomer { Com­pa­nyId = “AC”, Cus­tomerId = “Customer2”, User = “not-admin” },
new User­Cus­tomer { Com­pa­nyId = “AC”, Cus­tomerId = “Customer2”, User = “admin” },
new User­Cus­tomer { Com­pa­nyId = “not-AC”, Cus­tomerId = “Customer1”, User = “not-admin”     },
new User­Cus­tomer { Com­pa­nyId = “not-AC”, Cus­tomerId = “Customer1”, User = “admin” },
new User­Cus­tomer { Com­pa­nyId = “not-AC”, Cus­tomerId = “Customer2”, User = “not-admin” },
new User­Cus­tomer { Com­pa­nyId = “not-AC”, Cus­tomerId = “Customer2”, User = “admin” }
};
```

Using query expres­sion

```
var query =
from c in cus­tomers
join uc in user­Cus­tomers on
new { c.CompanyId, c.CustomerId } equals new { uc.CompanyId, uc.CustomerId }
where c.CompanyId == “AC” && uc.User == “admin“
select c;
```

Using lambda expres­sions

```
var lambda =  cus­tomers.Where(c => c.CompanyId == “AC”) // inner sequence
.Join(userCustomers.Where(uc => uc.User == “admin”), // outer sequence
c => new { c.CompanyId, c.CustomerId }, // inner key selec­tor
uc => new { uc.CompanyId, uc.CustomerId }, // outer key selec­tor
(c, uc) => c);
```

Both approach yields the same result (cus­tomer with com­pany Id “AC” and cus­tomer Id “Customer1”), but as you can see, lambda expres­sion is much harder to write and read!

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

Download [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/); it comes with built-in samples for learning LINQ.

Comment: i thought that was only the paid version that had loads of samples etc

Comment: The free version comes with samples too.

Answer (score 3):

Use Reflector .NET  :)