# Looping through JSON in a C# dictionary

Tags: c#, php, json, dictionary, associative-array

I am trying to implement a PHP function I have already made in C# but I have no idea of the syntax used in C# used to Navigate Dictionaries! (Associative arrays in PHP). What I am doing essentially is making a foreach loop to print each instance of a property in the associative array. I'm not sure if my question is completely clear so to make it easier, What would be the C# equivalent of this?

```
foreach ( $data->response->docs as $info )
{
    echo "{$info->EventId},";
    echo "{$info->VenueName},";
}
```

I just need a nudge in the right direction syntax wise.

Thanks

EDIT-

oops, when I posted this question I was tired. my problem is how to navigate a dictionary serialized from JSON. in my example I was parsing two properties from this sample data :-

```
{"responseHeader":{"status":0,"QTime":2},"response":{"facet_counts":{},"numFound":110,"docs":[{"VenueSEOLink":"/Aberdeen-Music-Hall-tickets-Aberdeen/venue/443660","VenueId":"10512085.....
```

etc etc....

So I am trying to figure out how to go down multiple levels through the dict. (C# equivalent of ->)

Answer (score 0):

In C#, you can use a `System.Collections.Dictionary` or a generic `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<TKey, TObject>`.  I recommend the generic dictionary because it is strongly-typed and you don't have to cast the contents every time you retrieve an object.

Assuming your EventId is an `int`, you can access it like this:

```
Dictionary<int, string> info = new Dictionary<int, string>();
int eventId = 42;
info[eventId] = "Some value";

var value = info[eventId];
// value = "Some value" as string
```

If you are using `string` keys just change the dictionary definition and key type from `int` to `string`.

To iterate on a dictionary (or any collection or other object that implements `IEnumerable`), you use essentially the same syntax as in PHP:

```
foreach (var item in info) {
  // Do something with item
}
```

[More info Systems.Collections.Generic.IDictionary is here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4ys34ea)

Comment: Try [this desrcription of converting json to C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611031/convert-json-string-to-c-sharp-object) or [this description of parsing json in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-to-parse-json-in-c)