# How to turn String (json-like) into Object

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

In my controller, I get a string that is JSON:

```
String json_string = this.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

That looks something like so:

```
{
    "21": {"Id":21,"DisplayOrder":3, ... snip ... },
    "333":{"Id":333,"DisplayOrder":2, ... snip ... },
    "591":{"Id":591,"DisplayOrder":1, ... snip ... }
}
```

I don't have a say in the structure of this JSON so can't format it into something without keys. They keys aren't necessary since the ID is within the Value of that Dictionary.

In any case, how do I convert `json_string` in such a way that allows me to pull out the only two items I want when I iterate over the 'rows' in that structure... Id, DisplayOrder?

Like so:

```
int Id = row_item.Id;
int DisplayOrder = row_item.DisplayOrder;
```

Thanks!
Eric

Comment: Is this what you're looking for?
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611031/convert-json-string-to-c-sharp-object][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611031/convert-json-string-to-c-sharp-object

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-to-parse-json-in-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string json = @"{
    ""21"": {""Id"":21,""DisplayOrder"":3},
    ""333"":{""Id"":333,""DisplayOrder"":2},
    ""591"":{""Id"":591,""DisplayOrder"":1}}";

var list = new JavaScriptSerializer()
               .Deserialize<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>>>(json)
               .Values
               .ToList();

Console.WriteLine(list[0]["Id"]); // <--21
```

You can also do the same thing with [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/)

```
var jObj = JsonConvert
           .DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>>>(json)
           .Values
           .ToList();

Console.WriteLine(jObj[0]["Id"]);
```

`dynamic` can be utilized too

```
var jObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(json)
            .Values
            .ToList();

Console.WriteLine(jObj[0].DisplayOrder);
```