# Deserialize Json file

Tags: c#, json

```
{
    "Location": "St Kilda", 
    "Name": "Movie Plaza theatre", 
    "Day": ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Tuesday","Friday","Saturday"]
}
```

I can't deserialize this Json. can anyone help me ?

Comment: put your some stuff here.

Comment: Too many tutorials/examples/existing questions available: no effort.

Comment: you have to show some effort of your own (for example, code you tried), and tell us what does not work, and how.

Comment: For example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611031/convert-json-string-to-c-sharp-object?lq=1 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18887739/convert-json-to-c-sharp-type?lq=1 (and any relevant web search)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create class of your json as below

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> Day { get; set; }
}
```

Then write some code as below to get data from json

```
JObject json = JObject.Parse(your json string); 
RootObject obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

**Update:**

```
Console.WriteLine(obj.Location);
Console.WriteLine(obj.Name);

foreach (var d in obj.Day)
{
    Console.WriteLine(d);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it works. Can you tell me how to show the data of this Json file?  coz i can only show the type of this list.

Comment: I am not able to get you. What you want ?

Comment: i used console.writeline in foreach to show the data in Json file, i can get the data of location and name, but i only get the type of the List not the data in this List.

Comment: static void PrintData(List<Data> data)
        {
            foreach (var item in data)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Location + item.Name + item.Day);
            }
        }

Comment: @Sam I update my answer please check.

Comment: Thank you very much . :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use the C# dynamic type to make things easier. This technique also makes re-factoring simpler as it does not rely on magic-strings.

**1.** JsonConvert.DeserializeObject
Use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(string json);`

Create your classes on JSON 2 C#. How it [read here](http://json2csharp.com/)

If any fields missing in the JSON data should simply be left NULL.

**2.** Deserializing JSON with Json.NET
You can also read [how deserializing JSON with Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/SerializingJSON.htm)

**3.** JsonConvert.Populate
You can also use `JsonConvert.Populate(json,obj);`
i.e. json is the json string,obj is the target object

Read more about [PopulateObject](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PopulateObject.htm)

Hope this help well.