# How to convert string into Json format?

Tags: asp.net

Am catching the Http response in string variable.I want to convert string into json.How to convert?

```
  string responseData;  
  HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;  
   if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)  
   {
         System.IO.StreamReader responseReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
         responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
   }
```

Comment: You mean you want `responseData` in JSON format? In what format is it? Or do you mean the `responseData` already is in JSON format, and you wish to read that JSON object?

Comment: Show your response data. Is it `HTML/JSON/XML`?

Answer (score 0):

First See this [previous discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611031/convert-json-string-to-c-sharp-object)

and if you used asp.net MVC , then try this below way

```
 [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult GetValues()
        {
         string responseData;  
         HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;  
         if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)  
         {
         System.IO.StreamReader responseReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
         responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
         }                 
         return Json(new { data = responseData}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
         }
```

Comment: he is using asp.net and c#