# Convert JSON to GenericList in C#?

Tags: c#, json, list, asp.net-mvc-4

This is my JSON and I am passing to the controller using `$.Ajax`

```
 [{"Id":["100"],"AdminId":2,"Type":"ReadWrite"},
 {"Id":["100"],"AdminId":3,"Type":"Read"}]

$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Home/Access",
            cache: false,
            data: { "data": UpdateData },
            async: true,
            success: function (response) {

            }
        });

 public JsonResult Access(string data)
    {
        var isUpdated = false;     
        return Json(isUpdated);
     }
```

How can I convert to generic list so that I can update my database. I need `Id`, `AdminId`, `Type` from JSON. *I don't want to create a new class.*

Comment: `I dont want to create a new class.` Why not? It doesn't take any time and is the most robust solution.

Comment: Any reason why you don't want to create a new class?  I guess your parameter could be `dynamic`, but why?

Comment: Also, your `id` is an array? Is it only supposed to ever have 1 member? Or can it have more than one? What is supposed to happen with more than 1? How would you map that?

Comment: @MattBurland  Because this is only one and small scenario. I want to keep it for one time use only.

Comment: @WPFRookie: So, it's a one-time use. It's only a small class. It takes about 2 minutes and you have something robust and strongly typed. And in the future when that "one-time" use class suddenly becomes a "used all over the place" class, you are all set.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22191376/1743997

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the inputs. As other said, creating a class is the most robust one, we can do like below also without using class.

```
var oSerializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
dynamic listData = oSerializer.DeserializeObject(data);

foreach (var obj in listData)
 {
    var Id = obj["Id"];
    var Type = obj["Type"];
 }
```

Comment: If you don't have a reason to use dynamic, then probably better not to use it. You should use a class.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use JSON.NET to deserialize it as a JObject and then you can index into the object. You also probably could deserialize it as dynamic

I don't really recommend doing this just because you can.