# convert json string to c# list of objects (string comes from request as NULL)

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, web-services

I have the following code to convert json string to list of objects:

```
        public class rest_all
        {
            public string restaurants { get; set; } 
        }


        public class rest_all_data
        {
            public string RestaurantName { get; set; }
            public string CategoryName { get; set; }
            public string FourSquareID { get; set; } 
        }


        public class rest_collection 
        {
            public IEnumerable<rest_all_data> rest_all_data { get; set; }
        }
```

and here is the main function:

```
public void AddRestaurantMultiple (rest_all rest_all)
        {
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            rest_collection collection = serializer.Deserialize<rest_collection>(rest_all.restaurants);
        }
```

the problem is that when I make an http request with a json string like this:

```
{"restaurants" : [{"RestaurantName":"a","CategoryName":"b","FourSquareID":"c"},{"RestaurantName":"d","CategoryName":"e","FourSquareID":"f"}]
```

it always gives me null at the `AddRestaurantMultiple` function...what is it am i doing wrong??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert Json String to C# Object List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22191167/convert-json-string-to-c-sharp-object-list)

Comment: What do you mean by "it always gives me a null"? That's very unclear. It would help if you could provide a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem, ideally using idiomatic .NET naming...

Comment: How are you "calling" to the class that contains the `AddRestaurantMultiple` function? Is this a client-side request for the JSON or server-side?

Comment: I am using fiddler to generate the request...and by null i mean when i send a request to the input of `AddRestaurantMultiple` function the `resaurant` string in `rest_all` class is always NULL

Answer (score 4):

Your model should be

```
public class Restaurant
{
    public string RestaurantName { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public string FourSquareID { get; set; }
}

public class rest_collection
{
    public List<Restaurant> restaurants { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
var result = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<rest_collection>(yourjson);
```

Comment: the problem is that when I do an http request using fiddler...the json string in the `AddRestaurantMultiple` always comes as null

Comment: @Abdallah Given your json in question above code works correctly. I don't know what/how you are doing with fiddler.

Comment: this is the message i send using fiddler....                                     `{"restaurants:[{"RestaurantName":"a","CategoryName":"b","FourSquareID":"c"},{"RestaurantName":"d","CategoryName":"e","FourSquareID":"f"}]}`

Comment: @Abdallah I don't know your server, its API  and what it expects as input to its methods. So I have no idea what you are doing...