# json data inside a list

Tags: c#, json, jquery-jtable

I have the following code and i need to use it inside a List<>.
Can someone help me on this?

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string url = "http://localhost:52148/api/federateds";

        using (var w = new WebClient())
        {
            var json_data = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                json_data = w.DownloadString(url);
            }
            catch (Exception) { }
        }

        List<federateds> federados = new ????;

    }
```

Comment: Already answered -
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22191167/convert-json-string-to-c-sharp-object-list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try JSON frameworks, like [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

With it your code would look like

```
List<federateds> federados = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<federateds>>(json_data);
```