# Trouble Deserializing JSON to DataTable

Tags: json.net, fastmember

I'm new to C# and I am working on deserializing a JSON response from an API and resending the reponse to a DataTable (and then to SQL Server).

I'm using JSON.NET and RestSharp.

I followed the answer that was outlined here [Convert Json String to C# Object List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22191167/convert-json-string-to-c-sharp-object-list?noredirect=1&lq=1) and was attempting to use FastMember to convert the object to a datatable but I was unsucessful.

Here is an example of the JSON Response:

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "messages": [],
  "success": true,
  "data": {
    "identifiers": [
      {
        "identifier": "123",
        "type": "cust_id",
        "active": true
      },
      {
        "identifier": "456",
        "type": "pid",
        "active": true
      }
    ],
    "activities": [
      {
        "identity": "transaction_6408496",
        "type": "bypass",
        "subtype": "pos",
        "subject": "made a purchase",
        "created_at": "2016-03-29T20:04:03-05:00",
        "source_url": "",
        "worth": 26,
        "awarded": 26
      }
    ],
    "transactions": [
      {
        "purchased_at": "2016-03-29T20:04:03-05:00",
        "created_at": "2016-03-29T20:05:21-05:00",
        "data_type": "pos",
        "transaction_items": [
          {
            "total_cents": 525,
            "price_cents": 525,
            "quantity": 1,
            "name": "Soda- Regular Fountain Soda, 24oz",
            "category": "NA Bev",
            "bucket": "Concessions"
          }
        ],
        "transaction_number": "25401170",
        "transaction_id": "25401170",
        "event_id": "",
        "location_id": "3163",
        "terminal_id": "34d8cd0fa430e17a",
        "member_id": "789",
        "table_number": ""
      },
      {
        "purchased_at": "2015-03-21T13:18:20-05:00",
        "created_at": "2015-03-23T02:14:46-05:00",
        "data_type": "pos",
        "transaction_items": [
          {
            "total_cents": 3315,
            "price_cents": 3315,
            "quantity": 1,
            "name": "YTH SMU FZ HOODIE 2-4T",
            "category": "KIDS",
            "bucket": "Merchandise"
          }
        ],
        "transaction_number": "",
        "transaction_id": "01-1047019",
        "event_id": "",
        "location_id": "0102",
        "terminal_id": "",
        "member_id": "789",
        "table_number": ""
      }
    ],
    "devices": [],
    "visits": [],
    "email": "me@ishfuseini.com",
    "email_deliverable": true,
    "first_name": "Ish",
    "last_name": "Fuseini",
    "fanfluence": "",
    "profile_url": "http://ishfuseini.com",
    "gender": "",
    "age": "",
    "relationship_status": "",
    "religion": "",
    "political": "",
    "location": "",
    "address": "",
    "city": "",
    "state": "",
    "zip": "",
    "birthdate": "",
    "phone": "",
    "social_handles": {
      "twitter": "",
      "foursquare": "",
      "facebook": "",
      "instagram": "",
      "tvtag": "",
      "shopify": "",
      "pinterest": "",
      "tumblr": ""
    },
    "created_at": "2014-09-26T17:10:37-05:00",
    "tc_accepted_at": "",
    "points_available": 26,
    "points_spent": 0,
    "total_points_earned": 26,
    "social_points": 0,
    "ticketing_points": 0,
    "membership_assignment": false,
    "category_spend": [
      {
        "name": "Concessions",
        "spend": 5.25
      },
      {
        "name": "Merchandise",
        "spend": 33.15
      }
    ],
    "ticketing_spend": 0,
    "pos_points": 26,
    "pos_spend": 38.4
  }
}
```

Here are the classes I generated from [json2csharp.com](http://json2csharp.com/)

```
public class Identifier
{
    public string identifier { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public bool active { get; set; }
}

public class Activity
{
    public string identity { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string subtype { get; set; }
    public string subject { get; set; }
    public string created_at { get; set; }
    public string source_url { get; set; }
    public int worth { get; set; }
    public int awarded { get; set; }
}

public class TransactionItem
{
    public int total_cents { get; set; }
    public int price_cents { get; set; }
    public int quantity { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string category { get; set; }
    public string bucket { get; set; }
}

public class Transaction
{
    public string purchased_at { get; set; }
    public string created_at { get; set; }
    public string data_type { get; set; }
    public List<TransactionItem> transaction_items { get; set; }
    public string transaction_number { get; set; }
    public string transaction_id { get; set; }
    public string event_id { get; set; }
    public string location_id { get; set; }
    public string terminal_id { get; set; }
    public string member_id { get; set; }
    public string table_number { get; set; }
}

public class SocialHandles
{
    public string twitter { get; set; }
    public string foursquare { get; set; }
    public string facebook { get; set; }
    public string instagram { get; set; }
    public string tvtag { get; set; }
    public string shopify { get; set; }
    public string pinterest { get; set; }
    public string tumblr { get; set; }
}

public class CategorySpend
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public double spend { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public List<Identifier> identifiers { get; set; }
    public List<Activity> activities { get; set; }
    public List<Transaction> transactions { get; set; }
    public List<object> devices { get; set; }
    public List<object> visits { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public bool email_deliverable { get; set; }
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string last_name { get; set; }
    public string fanfluence { get; set; }
    public string profile_url { get; set; }
    public string gender { get; set; }
    public string age { get; set; }
    public string relationship_status { get; set; }
    public string religion { get; set; }
    public string political { get; set; }
    public string location { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    public string zip { get; set; }
    public string birthdate { get; set; }
    public string phone { get; set; }
    public SocialHandles social_handles { get; set; }
    public string created_at { get; set; }
    public string tc_accepted_at { get; set; }
    public int points_available { get; set; }
    public int points_spent { get; set; }
    public int total_points_earned { get; set; }
    public int social_points { get; set; }
    public int ticketing_points { get; set; }
    public bool membership_assignment { get; set; }
    public List<CategorySpend> category_spend { get; set; }
    public int ticketing_spend { get; set; }
    public int pos_points { get; set; }
    public double pos_spend { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public List<object> messages { get; set; }
    public bool success { get; set; }
    public Data data { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my code:

```
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            var content = response.Content;



            //Deserialziing Response to Object
            var datafromjson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ActivityModels.RootObject>(content);

            DataTable table = new DataTable();


            using (var reader = ObjectReader.Create(datafromjson.data.ToString()))
            {
                table.Load(reader);
            }
```

Error:

```
    System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233086
  Message=Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: name
  ParamName=name
  Source=FastMember_dynamic
  StackTrace:
       at FastMember_dynamic.Char_1.get_Item(Object , String )
       at FastMember.ObjectReader.System.Data.IDataRecord.GetValues(Object[] values) in c:\Dev\fast-member\FastMember\ObjectReader.cs:line 300
       at System.Data.ProviderBase.DataReaderContainer.CommonLanguageSubsetDataReader.GetValues(Object[] values)
       at System.Data.ProviderBase.SchemaMapping.LoadDataRow()
       at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.FillLoadDataRow(SchemaMapping mapping)
       at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.FillFromReader(DataSet dataset, DataTable datatable, String srcTable, DataReaderContainer dataReader, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, DataColumn parentChapterColumn, Object parentChapterValue)
       at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, IDataReader dataReader, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords)
       at System.Data.Common.LoadAdapter.FillFromReader(DataTable[] dataTables, IDataReader dataReader, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords)
       at System.Data.DataTable.Load(IDataReader reader, LoadOption loadOption, FillErrorEventHandler errorHandler)
       at System.Data.DataTable.Load(IDataReader reader)
       at FanMaker_API.GetActivity..ctor() in C:\Users\Ismail Fuseini\Documents\projects\FanMaker_API\FanMaker_API\GetActivity.cs:line 67
       at FanMaker_API.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Ismail Fuseini\Documents\projects\FanMaker_API\FanMaker_API\Program.cs:line 22
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

I think the structure of the JSON is what is throwing me off. I tried to change the data type of the data class to a list but I would get an error asking me to change the JSON or change the type of object I'm deserializing the object to.

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems in your classes like created_at has to be datetime, etc. Also can't see your code for root object. Try this:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public object[] messages { get; set; }
    public bool success { get; set; }
    public Data data { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public Identifier[] identifiers { get; set; }
    public Activity[] activities { get; set; }
    public Transaction[] transactions { get; set; }
    public object[] devices { get; set; }
    public object[] visits { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public bool email_deliverable { get; set; }
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string last_name { get; set; }
    public string fanfluence { get; set; }
    public string profile_url { get; set; }
    public string gender { get; set; }
    public string age { get; set; }
    public string relationship_status { get; set; }
    public string religion { get; set; }
    public string political { get; set; }
    public string location { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    public string zip { get; set; }
    public string birthdate { get; set; }
    public string phone { get; set; }
    public Social_Handles social_handles { get; set; }
    public DateTime created_at { get; set; }
    public string tc_accepted_at { get; set; }
    public int points_available { get; set; }
    public int points_spent { get; set; }
    public int total_points_earned { get; set; }
    public int social_points { get; set; }
    public int ticketing_points { get; set; }
    public bool membership_assignment { get; set; }
    public Category_Spend[] category_spend { get; set; }
    public int ticketing_spend { get; set; }
    public int pos_points { get; set; }
    public float pos_spend { get; set; }
}

public class Social_Handles
{
    public string twitter { get; set; }
    public string foursquare { get; set; }
    public string facebook { get; set; }
    public string instagram { get; set; }
    public string tvtag { get; set; }
    public string shopify { get; set; }
    public string pinterest { get; set; }
    public string tumblr { get; set; }
}

public class Identifier
{
    public string identifier { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public bool active { get; set; }
}

public class Activity
{
    public string identity { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string subtype { get; set; }
    public string subject { get; set; }
    public DateTime created_at { get; set; }
    public string source_url { get; set; }
    public int worth { get; set; }
    public int awarded { get; set; }
}

public class Transaction
{
    public DateTime purchased_at { get; set; }
    public DateTime created_at { get; set; }
    public string data_type { get; set; }
    public Transaction_Items[] transaction_items { get; set; }
    public string transaction_number { get; set; }
    public string transaction_id { get; set; }
    public string event_id { get; set; }
    public string location_id { get; set; }
    public string terminal_id { get; set; }
    public string member_id { get; set; }
    public string table_number { get; set; }
}

public class Transaction_Items
{
    public int total_cents { get; set; }
    public int price_cents { get; set; }
    public int quantity { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string category { get; set; }
    public string bucket { get; set; }
}

public class Category_Spend
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public float spend { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I updated the classes but I feel like I'm not utilizing fast member properly.

I'm getting the following error message:

`An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in FastMember_dynamic
`
Do I need to change the json response to a list in order to create a DataTable?