# How to deserialize list of objects from json

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

```
Thats my class.

class MyClass1 : IInterface1
{
    public MyClass1()
    {
        this.Interface2s = new List<IInterface2>();
    }

    public string strI1 { get; set; }
    public int intI1 { get; set; }
    public IList<IInterface2> Interface2s { get; set; }
    public int intC1 { get; set; }
}
```

In application I serialized it with some random values. Result:

```
{
  "strI1": "strI1",
  "intI1": 2,
  "Interface2s": [
    {
      "intI2": 111
    },
    {
      "intI2": 222
    },
    {
      "intI2": 333
    }
  ]
}
```

Then, i want to deserialize that string back, but I'm loosing values in my IList

```
result of deserialization next:
{
  "strI1": "strI1",
  "intI1": 2,
  "Interface2s": [
    {
      "intI2": 0
    },
    {
      "intI2": 0
    },
    {
      "intI2": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

To deserialize interface I'm using that example http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeWithDependencyInjection.htm

I need to deserialize values in list too. Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you use to serialize your class into json?

Comment: There are a very large number of these questions on stackoverflow already. Does none of those answers help you? Please try, and I am sure you can figure it out

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Json String to C# Object List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22191167/convert-json-string-to-c-sharp-object-list)

Comment: Or [Convert JSON String To C# Object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611031/convert-json-string-to-c-sharp-object) or [How to Convert JSON object to Custom C# object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246694/how-to-convert-json-object-to-custom-c-sharp-object) or about 100 other questions. Please check to see if a question has been asked already before asking.

Comment: Can you show IInterface2. Btw deserialization to interface is problem.

Comment: Interface2 has one property intI2 {get;set;}, thats all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My advice is just use http://www.newtonsoft.com/json

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(target)
```

and to deserialize

```
JsonConvert.DeSerializeObject<MyClass1>(target)
```

And it should just be as simple as that.

Comment: Sorry for poor example, but I'm using json.net and there is the problem

Comment: 'JsonConvert.DeSerializeObject<MyClass1>(target)' returns me MyClass and List in it with 3 empty objects.

Comment: Try experimenting with http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializetypenamehandling.htm during serialization. That might be the issue, it could be deserializing the interface to the wrong type, so by embedding type information, that could solve your issue. @RiseAgainst

Comment: I found the issue, but not solution... The issue is that json deserealize interface, so there is no values. I nedd him to deserialize class, that inherit my interface.

Comment: Yes @RiseAgainst thats why you need to tell Json.Net to add the type information when it serializes. Then it will know which types to deserialize