# Json to list in C#

Tags: c#, json, list, parsing

I have a json file this is its format:

```
{"resultset": {"row": [
       {"field": [1001001, 1, 1, 1, "In the beginning God{After \\\"God,\\\" the Hebrew has the two letters \\\"Aleph Tav\\\" (the first and last letters of the Hebrew alphabet) as a grammatical marker.} created the heavens and the earth."]},  
       {"field": [1001002, 1, 1, 2, "Now the earth was formless and empty. Darkness was on the surface of the deep. God's Spirit was hovering over the surface of the waters."]} 
]}}
```

How can i store this in a **List?** I want to store all the values in the **"field"** in a list. 
**Note: I have a huge collection of data.**

Comment: You can use newtonsoft nuget. To Deserialize Object into List.

Answer (score 1):

Create an object like this:

```
public class Field
{
    /*Your properties here*/
}

public class Row
{
    public List<Field> field { get; set; }
}

public class Resultset
{
    public List<Row> row { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Resultset resultset { get; set; }
}
```

Deserialize the JSON to the rootobject, so you can browse to the list of fields.

Comment: can you show me how to do Deserialize ? and example on my json string?

Comment: Your question is marked a duplicate, and there are a lot of questions here already addressing the use of the json.NET package.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22191167/convert-json-string-to-c-sharp-object-list