# How to convert deserialize JSON object to class

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have an array object which I have deserialized using Newtonsoft JSON.

Now I need to convert the deserialized object to class properties.

My deserialized object is: -

```
[
  [
    {
      "filterName": "Is Active",
      "filterformattedValue": "True",
      "filterValue": true,
      "view": "Demo/UsersbyFunction"
    },    
    {
      "filterName": "Sbg",
      "filterformattedValue": "PMT",
      "filterValue": "PMT",
      "view": "Demo/UsersbyFunction"
    },
    {
      "filterName": "Sbg",
      "filterformattedValue": "SPS",
      "filterValue": "SPS",
      "view": "Demo/UsersbyFunction"
    }
  ],
  [    
    {
      "filterName": "Sbg",
      "filterformattedValue": "CORP",
      "filterValue": "CORP",
      "view": "Demo/UsersbyFunction"
    },
    {
      "filterName": "Sbg",
      "filterformattedValue": "PMT",
      "filterValue": "PMT",
      "view": "Demo/UsersbyFunction"
    },
    {
      "filterName": "Sbg",
      "filterformattedValue": "SPS",
      "filterValue": "SPS",
      "view": "Demo/UsersbyFunction"
    }
  ]
]
```

and my class is: -

```
public class Filter
{
    public string filterName { get; set; }
    public string filterformattedValue { get; set; }
    public string filterValue { get; set; }
    public string view { get; set; }
}
```

Now I need to make an Array object of class Filter. 
Is there any way to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add the code how you serialize the JSON

Comment: Check this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22191167/convert-json-string-to-c-sharp-object-list

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov The json itself is a single object (it starts with a **{**)

Comment: @SirRufo, I am getting serialized object from angular application.

and I am using this code to deserialize it
var arr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Filter>>(HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["arr"]);

Comment: The current data is **not valid** json - you cannot deserialize it with JSON.Net

Answer (score 2):

Edited to the new json structure:
Ok, then you have a two dimensional object:

```
string str = @"[  [    {      ""filterName"": ""Is Active"",      ""filterformattedValue"": ""True"",      ""filterValue"": true,      ""view"": ""Demo/UsersbyFunction""    },        {      ""filterName"": ""Sbg"",      ""filterformattedValue"": ""PMT"",      ""filterValue"": ""PMT"",      ""view"": ""Demo/UsersbyFunction""    },    {      ""filterName"": ""Sbg"",      ""filterformattedValue"": ""SPS"",      ""filterValue"": ""SPS"",      ""view"": ""Demo/UsersbyFunction""    }  ],  [        {      ""filterName"": ""Sbg"",      ""filterformattedValue"": ""CORP"",      ""filterValue"": ""CORP"",      ""view"": ""Demo/UsersbyFunction""    },    {     ""filterName"": ""Sbg"",      ""filterformattedValue"": ""PMT"",      ""filterValue"": ""PMT"",      ""view"": ""Demo/UsersbyFunction""    },    {      ""filterName"":""Sbg"",      ""filterformattedValue"": ""SPS"",      ""filterValue"": ""SPS"",      ""view"": ""Demo/UsersbyFunction""    }  ]]";
List<List<Filter>> filters = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<Filter>>>(str);
```

Or if you prefer with arrays:

```
Filter[][] filters = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Filter[][]>(str);
```

Comment: JSON is having array of object. This will not solve my issue.
In your JSON you have added one part of array.

Comment: @Sagar Your JSON is **not valid**. Maybe you made a mistake with copy/paste, added some chars or you really get an invalid json. Please check and update the question.

Comment: @Jesus, only thing is, remove first and last outermost curly braces. You can reverify that on https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: I've checked before post and I've got a list of two lists of three Filter objects. How are you deserializing the json?

Comment: @Sagar - this solution works using the JSON from the current version of your question, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/YnaTVr for a demo.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON structure seems to be wrong. Verify the same on https://jsonlint.com  Remove the outermost curly braces and then try this

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Filter>>>(your_JSON_String)
```

Comment: You can try it with any, but invalid data will never produce a valid result

Comment: Removing the outermost curly braces from the JSON structure should fix it. @SirRufo

Comment: Just as a guess from me: The OP added the curly braces manually to the sample data ;o)

Comment: @SirRufo, this JSON is a collection of an array of array type object.

Comment: Corrected JSON structure.

Comment: @Sagar What kind of output do you expect? Filter[][] (array of array of Filter) or List<List<Filter>>?

Comment: @SirRufo, In my web application i have collection of array type of array. While posting it to web api i have converted it into string. 
In api i am deserializing string object to assign to my class Filter. But not getting any luck.

Comment: @TejasHedly, your solution won't work. Object values are null.

Comment: @Sagar,  The value of filterValue in the first array has a boolean and you are trying to parse that to string. Try changing that to a string and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [Cinchoo ETL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChoETL.JSON/) - an open source library for parsing / creating JSON files.

```
using (var jr = new ChoJSONReader<Filter>("sample10.json")
    )
{
    foreach (var x in jr)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"FilterName: {x.filterName}");
        Console.WriteLine($"FilterformattedValue: {x.filterformattedValue}");
        Console.WriteLine($"filterValue : {x.filterValue}");
        Console.WriteLine($"View: {x.view}");
    }
}
```

Disclosure: I'm the author of this library.