# Extracting Information from json string and add it to a list in C#

Tags: c#, .net, json

I am new in json. I want information of different users and add them to a **dataGridView**  or **dataTable** or **dataSet** in c# (.net development). Information sample is (The json is valid):

```
{
    "JrPwbApfIHbQhCUmVIoiVJcPYv93": {
        "address": "Jessore",
        "name": "Dev"
    },
    "iBRZAyn8TQTOgKTcByGOvJjL9ZB3": {
        "address": "Bogra",
        "name": "Kumar Saikat"
    }
}
```

I want them like this :

---

User1 | Jessore | Dev

---

User2  | Bogra | Kumar Saikat

Even it would help if I could make a list for all of them.

I believe I was able to deserialise them (not sure at all) by
`var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<user>(json);`

where user is a class.

```
 public class Item
{

    public string name;
    public string address;

}
```

from [this question-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22191167/convert-json-string-to-c-sharp-object-list). From [this tutorial](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm) I am able to get values if property is known. But in my case my property would be unknown, (string "User1","User2" would be random, since I will get them from a database). Any help and light on this matter would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I do not understand this part of the question: *But in my case my property would be unknown, (string "User1","User2" would be random, since I will get them from a database)* Could you say more about that?

Comment: @John I think OP means the property names `JrPwbApfIHbQhCUmVIoiVJcPYv93` and `iBRZAyn8TQTOgKTcByGOvJjL9ZB3`

Comment: OP I've removed your `visual-studio` tag because this is not a question about the Visual Studio IDE.

Answer (score 6):

You're looking at a JSON dictionary, so just deserialize it as such:

```
public static Dictionary<string,Item> ParseJson(string source)
{
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,Item>>(source);
}
```

If you call it like this:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var input = @"{'JrPwbApfIHbQhCUmVIoiVJcPYv93': {'address': 'Jessore','name': 'Dev' }, 'iBRZAyn8TQTOgKTcByGOvJjL9ZB3': {'address': 'Bogra','name': 'Kumar Saikat'}}";

    var result = ParseJson(input);

    foreach (var r in result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Key={0};Name={1};Address={2}", r.Key, r.Value.name, r.Value.address);
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
Key=JrPwbApfIHbQhCUmVIoiVJcPYv93;Name=Dev;Address=Jessore
Key=iBRZAyn8TQTOgKTcByGOvJjL9ZB3;Name=Kumar Saikat;Address=Bogra
```

This example dumps the list to the console, but you could easily modify the `for` loop to add to a list instead.

See my example on [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PiJc0e)

Comment: Short and Precise !! Thanks a lot Mr. John Wu !!

Answer (score 0):

Can use the nuget package Newtonsoft.Json. This code gives you what you are looking for:

```
  using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var json =
                "{\"JrPwbApfIHbQhCUmVIoiVJcPYv93\":{\"address\":\"Jessore\",\"name\":\"Dev\"}," +
                "\"iBRZAyn8TQTOgKTcByGOvJjL9ZB3\":{\"address\":\"Bogra\",\"name\":\"Kumar Saikat\"}}";


            var o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

            var items = new List<Item>();

            foreach (dynamic x in o as IEnumerable)
            {
                var i = new Item();
                var y = x.First;
                i.Name = y.name.Value;
                i.Address = y.address.Value;
                items.Add(i);
            }
        }

        public class Item
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Address { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Your situation is a bit strange as those autocreated names like 
"JrPwbApfIHbQhCUmVIoiVJcPYv93" or else it's easier, but should be fairly easy code.

Keep in mind I use "dynamic" there which means problems will hit you at runtime NOT design time as it's not checked.

Comment: Ok after seeing John Wu's comment above me, that is a much better solution than mine. Leaving this here as an example, but use his please.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to deserialize would be as below

```
var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Item>>(data);
```

In the code sample you have posted, your "**user**" class name is **Item** but you are trying to deserialize using "**User**" in your code. Also please note that you cannot directly directly deserialize data into users list as it is present as a value of some random strings.

```
var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<user>(json);
```

For your code to deserialize correctly, your json format should be as below :

```
{
{
    "address": "Jessore",
    "name": "Dev"
},
{
    "address": "Bogra",
    "name": "Kumar Saikat"
}
```

}