# Extracting Information from a particular node of json string and add it to a list in C#

Tags: c#, .net, json

I am new in json. I want information user in various time and add them to diffrent lists.

My json text is like this -

```
{    "201322052":{  
  "Sat Aug 04 04:14:03":"https://blablabla",
  "Sat Aug 04 04:19:55":"https://blablabla2"},
"Doctor 201322052":{  
  "Sat Aug 04 04:19:35":"https://bla bla bla 3" }, 

"JrPwbApfIHbQhCUmVIoiVJcPYv93":{ 
"Sat Aug 04 04:02:47":{  
     "Misc":"sdasd",
     "Product":"asd",
     "address":"sd",
     "name":"Dr. Bua"
  },
  "Sat Aug 04 04:03:21":{  
     "Misc":"sdasd",
     "Product":"asd",
     "address":"sd",
     "name":"Dr. Bua"
  },
  "Sat Aug 04 04:03:28":{  
     "Misc":"sdasd",
     "Product":"asd",
     "address":"sd",
     "name":"Dr. Bua"
  },
  "Sat Aug 04 04:03:31":{  
     "Misc":"sdasd",
     "Product":"asd",
     "address":"sd",
     "name":"Dr. Bua"
  }
   }}
```

from a firebase database. I want to extract information of "**JrPwbApfIHbQhCUmVIoiVJcPYv93**" in this format-

---

DocName-----------Adress------Product----------Misc-------time

---

Dr. Bua---------Mirpur---------asd-------------sdsds------Sat Aug 04 04:02:47

---

Dr. Bua---------Mirpur---------asd-------------sdsds------Sat Aug 04 04:03:28

---

Dr. Bua---------Mirpur---------asd-------------sdsds------Sat July 04 04:03:28

I guess you get the idea. In my last [question about extracting information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51489048/extracting-information-from-json-string-and-add-it-to-a-list-in-c-sharp) I got a huge help from Mr. John Wu. I understand I need to do the same in here, but cannot get how to extract  node "**JrPwbApfIHbQhCUmVIoiVJcPYv93**" from whole json separately and then apply that again.

Comment: Why didn't accept the answer provided to the question you liked to?

Comment: You can follow a similar structure for this data as well.. Load the JSON. get the desired key value as a JObject and parse it as a dictionary.

Comment: Why is this not a duplicate of [Extracting Information from json string and add it to a list in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51489048/3744182)?  Do you not know how to filter out the `"201322052"` and `"Doctor 201322052"` properties whose values are inconsistent with the schema?

Comment: @Nkoshi, what is the code format to get the desired key?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for bothering, all I needed to do is

`JObject jobject = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
 JObject user = (JObject)jobject["JrPwbApfIHbQhCUmVIoiVJcPYv93"];`

user.toString() gives the following data

```
{     "Sat Aug 04 04:02:47":{  
  "Misc":"sdasd",
  "Product":"asd",
  "address":"sd",
  "name":"Dr. Bua"},"Sat Aug 04 04:03:21":{  
  "Misc":"sdasd",
  "Product":"asd",
  "address":"sd",
  "name":"Dr. Bua",
"Sat Aug 04 04:03:28":{  
  "Misc":"sdasd",
  "Product":"asd",
  "address":"sd",
  "name":"Dr. Bua"},
"Sat Aug 04 04:03:31":{  
  "Misc":"sdasd",
  "Product":"asd",
  "address":"sd",
  "name":"Dr. Bua"}}
```

which I actually needed. Then I extracted the information separately by [this help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51489048/extracting-information-from-json-string-and-add-it-to-a-list-in-c-sharp) previously provided. Thank you everyone for your response.