# Json.NET - deserialising and parsing json data in winforms

Tags: c#, .net, json, winforms, json.net

I am using Newtonsoft Json.net to try and parse some Json data from a file in my C# WinForms application, however I am running into a problem when I read in the data. 
I read the data into a string and then deserialise it into my json object but the object is always null and holds no data.
**My Json data/string**

```
{
  "titles": {
    "Title": "Write your title here", 
    "SubTitle": "Write your subtitle here" 
  },

  "signees": {
    "SigneeTitle0": "Name of the first signee here", 
    "SigneeTitle1": "Name of the second signee here", 
    "SigneeTitle2": "Name of the third signee here" 
  }
}
```

**Json Object**

```
public class JsonTitles
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string SubTitle { get; set; }
}
```

**Code to read in json data**

```
   public void ReadFormDataFile(string fileLocation)
    {
        string tmp = File.ReadAllText(fileLocation);
        JsonTitles titles = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonTitles>(tmp);
    }
```

I know that the data is being read in correctly as I can see it in my tmp string when debugging.
Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Your object doesn’t conform to the JSON. Where’s `titles`?

Comment: Your JSON object does not correspond to the input JSON string.

Comment: Use **Paste Json As Classes** to let VS create classes for you

Comment: ARg wrong dupe target : this one better https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22191167/convert-json-string-to-c-sharp-object-list

Comment: Great, thanks. Didn't know that Paste Json As Classes even existed!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the class which is corresponding to the whole input string and not only to some part of it. So you can use class like below:

```
public class InputObject{
    public TitlesClass titles {get;set;}
    public SigneesClass signees {get;set;}
}

public class TitlesClass {
    public string Title {get;set;}
    public string SubTitle {get;set;}
}

public class SigneesClass {
    public string SigneeTitle0 {get;set;}
    public string SigneeTitle1 {get;set;}
    public string SigneeTitle2 {get;set;}
}

public void ReadFormDataFile(string fileLocation)
{
    string tmp = File.ReadAllText(fileLocation);
    InputObject parsedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<InputObject>(tmp);
}
```