# How to extract multiple array of objects from Json data containing multiple array of objects?

Tags: javascript, c#, json, model-view-controller

I have a Json data which contains multiple array of objects sends by mvc  controller. I need to extract those array differently. I want *getEmailBasicData* array, *getEmailParticipantData* array, *getEmailDocumentData* array individually How can I do that?  Here is my code-

```
"{
  "$id": "1",
  "getEmailBasicData": [
    {
      "$id": "2",
      "notificationId": 23,
      "subject": "final test",
      "message": "<p>this is body</p>\n",
      "sendStatus": -1,
      "lastSendTime": null
    },
    {
      "$id": "3",
      "notificationId": 24,
      "subject": "final subject",
      "message": "<p>final body</p>\n",
      "sendStatus": -1,
      "lastSendTime": null
    },
    {
      "$id": "12",
      "notificationId": 33,
      "subject": "Final Test",
      "message": "<p>Final body</p>\n",
      "sendStatus": -1,
      "lastSendTime": null
    }
  ],
  "getEmailParticipantData": [
    {
      "$id": "13",
      "id": 55,
      "notificationId": 23,
      "employeeId": -1,
      "name": "here is the name",
      "emailAddress": "whatever@gmail.com",
      "contactNo": null
    },
    {
      "$id": "14",
      "id": 56,
      "notificationId": 23,
      "employeeId": -1,
      "name": "another name",
      "emailAddress": "someone@gmail.com",
      "contactNo": null
    } ],
    "getEmailDocumentData": [
    {
      "$id": "36",
      "id": 40,
      "notificationId": 23,
      "docId": 1,
      "attachmentLocation": "1_1_50474603_2287746231437248_8529393497499762688_n.jpg"
    },
       {
      "$id": "46",
      "id": 50,
      "notificationId": 33,
      "docId": 1,
      "attachmentLocation": 
 "1_1_50474603_2287746231437248_8529393497499762688_n.jpg"
    }
  ]
}"
```

Comment: Deserialize with `JSON.parse` if you cant fetch it to object right away. You should be able.

Comment: Try like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/22191376/4588756

Comment: Yeah !! Got it. After using  JSON.Parse(), it's working. many many thanks for your  quick response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `.` operator to access

```js
var a={
  "$id": "1",
  "getEmailBasicData": [
    {
      "$id": "2",
      "notificationId": 23,
      "subject": "final test",
      "message": "<p>this is body</p>\n",
      "sendStatus": -1,
      "lastSendTime": null
    },
    {
      "$id": "3",
      "notificationId": 24,
      "subject": "final subject",
      "message": "<p>final body</p>\n",
      "sendStatus": -1,
      "lastSendTime": null
    },
    {
      "$id": "12",
      "notificationId": 33,
      "subject": "Final Test",
      "message": "<p>Final body</p>\n",
      "sendStatus": -1,
      "lastSendTime": null
    }
  ],
  "getEmailParticipantData": [
    {
      "$id": "13",
      "id": 55,
      "notificationId": 23,
      "employeeId": -1,
      "name": "Md Rashedul Islam",
      "emailAddress": "rashed.cse08@gmail.com",
      "contactNo": null
    },
    {
      "$id": "14",
      "id": 56,
      "notificationId": 23,
      "employeeId": -1,
      "name": "Akash",
      "emailAddress": "akash@ravensystemstld.com",
      "contactNo": null
    } ],
    "getEmailDocumentData": [
    {
      "$id": "36",
      "id": 40,
      "notificationId": 23,
      "docId": 1,
      "attachmentLocation": "1_1_50474603_2287746231437248_8529393497499762688_n.jpg"
    },
       {
      "$id": "46",
      "id": 50,
      "notificationId": 33,
      "docId": 1,
      "attachmentLocation": 
 "1_1_50474603_2287746231437248_8529393497499762688_n.jpg"
    }
  ]
}
var basic=a.getEmailBasicData;
var doc=a.getEmailDocumentData;
var participants=a.getEmailParticipantData;
console.log(basic);
console.log(doc);
console.log(participants);
```

Comment: It was not working like this. But It worked when I pass the Json data through JSON.Parse() method. After parsing, it's working like you said. Thanks for your quick response

Answer (score 1):

You can use [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```js
let obj = {"$id":"1","getEmailBasicData":[{"$id":"2","notificationId":23,"subject":"finaltest","message":"<p>thisisbody</p>\n","sendStatus":-1,"lastSendTime":null},{"$id":"3","notificationId":24,"subject":"finalsubject","message":"<p>finalbody</p>\n","sendStatus":-1,"lastSendTime":null},{"$id":"12","notificationId":33,"subject":"FinalTest","message":"<p>Finalbody</p>\n","sendStatus":-1,"lastSendTime":null}],"getEmailParticipantData":[{"$id":"13","id":55,"notificationId":23,"employeeId":-1,"name":"MdRashedulIslam","emailAddress":"rashed.cse08@gmail.com","contactNo":null},{"$id":"14","id":56,"notificationId":23,"employeeId":-1,"name":"Akash","emailAddress":"akash@ravensystemstld.com","contactNo":null}],"getEmailDocumentData":[{"$id":"36","id":40,"notificationId":23,"docId":1,"attachmentLocation":"1_1_50474603_2287746231437248_8529393497499762688_n.jpg"},{"$id":"46","id":50,"notificationId":33,"docId":1,"attachmentLocation":"1_1_50474603_2287746231437248_8529393497499762688_n.jpg"}]}

const {getEmailBasicData,getEmailDocumentData,getEmailParticipantData} = obj

console.log(getEmailBasicData,getEmailDocumentData,getEmailParticipantData)
```

Comment: It was not working like this. But It worked when I pass the Json data through JSON.Parse() method. After parsing, it's working like you said. Thanks for your quick response.