# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Apps.RootObject>' to 'Apps'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm trying to convert JSON object into C# list. The JSON object is coming from API.

I referred [this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22191167/convert-json-string-to-c-sharp-object-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22191167/convert-json-string-to-c-sharp-object-list)

This is how I'm getting the data:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Apps>> getApps()
{
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "apps");
    var response = await _client_SB.SendAsync(request);
    var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Apps model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Apps.RootObject>>(json);

    return model;
}
```

Apps class looks like this -

```
public class Apps
{
    public class First
    {
        public string href { get; set; }
    }

    public class Last
    {
        public string href { get; set; }
    }

    public class Next
    {
        public string href { get; set; }
    }

    public class Pagination
    {
        public int total_results { get; set; }
        public int total_pages { get; set; }
        public First first { get; set; }
        public Last last { get; set; }
        public Next next { get; set; }
        public object previous { get; set; }
    }

    public class Data
    {
        public List<object> buildpacks { get; set; }
        public string stack { get; set; }
    }

    public class Lifecycle
    {
        public string type { get; set; }
        public Data data { get; set; }
    }

    public class Data2
    {
        public string guid { get; set; }
    }

    public class Space
    {
        public Data2 data { get; set; }
    }

    public class Relationships
    {
        public Space space { get; set; }
    }

    public class Self
    {
        public string href { get; set; }
    }

    public class EnvironmentVariables
    {
        public string href { get; set; }
    }

    public class Space2
    {
        public string href { get; set; }
    }

    public class Processes
    {
        public string href { get; set; }
    }

    public class RouteMappings
    {
        public string href { get; set; }
    }

    public class Packages
    {
        public string href { get; set; }
    }

    public class CurrentDroplet
    {
        public string href { get; set; }
    }

    public class Droplets
    {
        public string href { get; set; }
    }

    public class Tasks
    {
        public string href { get; set; }
    }

    public class Start
    {
        public string href { get; set; }
        public string method { get; set; }
    }

    public class Stop
    {
        public string href { get; set; }
        public string method { get; set; }
    }

    public class Links
    {
        public Self self { get; set; }
        public EnvironmentVariables environment_variables { get; set; }
        public Space2 space { get; set; }
        public Processes processes { get; set; }
        public RouteMappings route_mappings { get; set; }
        public Packages packages { get; set; }
        public CurrentDroplet current_droplet { get; set; }
        public Droplets droplets { get; set; }
        public Tasks tasks { get; set; }
        public Start start { get; set; }
        public Stop stop { get; set; }
    }

    public class Labels
    {
        public string a { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
    }

    public class Annotations
    {
    }

    public class Metadata
    {
        public Labels labels { get; set; }
        public Annotations annotations { get; set; }
    }

    public class Resource
    {
        public string guid { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string state { get; set; }
        public DateTime created_at { get; set; }
        public DateTime updated_at { get; set; }
        public Lifecycle lifecycle { get; set; }
        public Relationships relationships { get; set; }
        public Links links { get; set; }
        public Metadata metadata { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public Pagination pagination { get; set; }
        public List<Resource> resources { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Error on `Apps model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Apps.RootObject>>(json);`

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'Apps'

Can anyone help me with this? I'm new to .net

Update:

My Json Object
https://pastebin.com/wHXsVNa1

Comment: You probably need to change `Apps model` to `List<Apps.RootObject> models`.

Comment: You are deserializing your json data as `List<Apps.RootObject>` but you are defining your variable `model` as `Apps`. The error simply states that `List<Apps.RootObject>` cannot be converted to `Apps` type, so, what does your json data represent?

Comment: I changed to this `List<Apps.RootObject> models = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Apps.RootObject>>(json);` and getting error `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Apps.RootObject>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Apps>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

Comment: @Icepickle I have updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are clearly misunderstanding what `Apps` class you defined actually consists of.
It actually has 0 (zero!) properties and multiple inner class definitions.

Your actual Apps class (according to JSON you've provided) is `Apps.RootObject` class.
If I understand correctly what your JSON consists of, actual applications are in resource array, so they are represented with `Resource` class.

So:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Apps.Resource>> getApps()
{
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "apps");
    var response = await _client_SB.SendAsync(request);
    var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    // Get apps collection with pagination
    Apps.RootObject model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Apps.RootObject>(json);
    // Return only apps
    return model.resources;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear if you are getting Apps list or a single Apps object.

Assuming your are getting lists of Apps.

Change:

```
Apps model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Apps.RootObject>>(json);
```

to:

```
var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Apps>(json);
```

Comment: I'm getting json object with multiple apps having properties that i have mentioned in my Apps class

Comment: Can you post a JSON sample?

Comment: I’ve updated my answer. Your json is not an array. Its object.

Answer (score -1):

Jojo, after changing your '`models`' to type '`List<Apps.Rootobject>` ' you need to change your method '`getapps`' return type also to '`Task <IEnumerable<Apps.Rootobject>>` '.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean can you show me an example plz

Comment: please check comment again. Did some formatting some part of comment was not shown properly by stackoverflow. implemented suggested formatting.

Comment: This is not really an answer

Comment: @icepickle - looking at comments provided by you and reply by jojo tried to solve his current problem. That it was giving him type cast problem. Thought it will solve his current problem. Anyway good thing he got his answer.