# Parse JSON String into List C# VMC

Tags: c#, vmc

**Dear all my brother i have this Json Data**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxxh1.png)

```
0: Object { no: "1", project: "Rosato", job_type: "គ្រឿងសង្ហារឹម", … }
1: Object { no: "2", project: "KPS", job_type: "គ្រឿងសង្ហារឹម", … }
```

i want to extract it in to c# List or data table please help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22191167/convert-json-string-to-c-sharp-object-list

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) as  a reference in your project

```
string myJsonString = MyMethodToReadJsonAsStringFromDataSource(dataSourceConnection);
IEnumerable<dynamic> myObjects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(myJsonString);
foreach(dynamic myObject in myObjects)
{
     // access to your abject
     string no = myObject.no;
     string project = myObject.project;
     string job_type = myObject.job_type;
}
```

You can replace dynamic with a class you create that maps to your json object so you can have full access to your object at compiler time.

Answer (score -1):

Please refer: [How to serialize and deserialize (marshal and unmarshal) JSON in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to)