# JSON with multiple arrays to C# arraylist or list or custom object and display as details

Tags: c#, json, winforms, json.net

I have the below JSON content in a file.

```
[{
        "projectCode": "ICSM000003SM_Prj1",
        "name": "Story mapping",
        "id": "5eeb94710ce4e01aac9ac3e2",
        "workRequests": [{
                "name": "test issue",
                "project": "5eeb94710ce4e01aac9ac3e2",
                "id": "5eeb94930ce4e01aac9ac3ef",
                "url": "http://example.com/form?collectorid=5eeb94930ce4e01aac9ac3ef&icentid=5e8eff6b99ba793a08461372&projectid=5eeb94710ce4e01aac9ac3e2&source=mail"
            },
            {
                "name": "defect issue collector",
                "project": "5eeb94710ce4e01aac9ac3e2",
                "id": "5eee564170e0d814d0dd5288",
                "url": "http://example.com/form?collectorid=5eee564170e0d814d0dd5288&icentid=5e8eff6b99ba793a08461372&projectid=5eeb94710ce4e01aac9ac3e2&source=mail"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "projectCode": "ICSM000001IC100",
        "name": "issue collector",
        "id": "5e8eff7c99ba793a08461375",
        "workRequests": [{
                "name": "SE issue collector",
                "project": "5e8eff7c99ba793a08461375",
                "id": "5e96864599ba7923a488194a",
                "url": "http://example.com/form?collectorid=5e96864599ba7923a488194a&icentid=5e8eff6b99ba793a08461372&projectid=5e8eff7c99ba793a08461375&source=mail"
            },
            {
                "name": "test",
                "project": "5e8eff7c99ba793a08461375",
                "id": "5ee36aef1ad1de3c10fa9aa6",
                "url": "http://example.com/form?collectorid=5ee36aef1ad1de3c10fa9aa6&icentid=5e8eff6b99ba793a08461372&projectid=5e8eff7c99ba793a08461375&source=mail"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "projectCode": "ICSM000005SM_SP",
        "name": "Single project sm",
        "id": "5eee566970e0d814d0dd5289",
        "workRequests": [{
            "name": "feedback collector",
            "project": "5eee566970e0d814d0dd5289",
            "id": "5eee568c70e0d814d0dd5296",
            "url": "http://example.com/form?collectorid=5eee568c70e0d814d0dd5296&icentid=5e8eff6b99ba793a08461372&projectid=5eee566970e0d814d0dd5289&source=mail"
        }]
    }
]
```

Note: The above JSON content is dynamic. Its format is the same, but all values might change when I consume a REST API from the application.

Below is my code for converting JSON to treeview, but I want to display it in List or Details format.

```
public static void AddObjectNodes(JObject @object, string name, TreeNodeCollection parent)
    {
        var node = new TreeNode(name);
    //    if ()
        parent.Add(node);

        foreach (var property in @object.Properties())
        {
            AddTokenNodes(property.Value, property.Name, node.Nodes);
        }
    }
    private static void AddTokenNodes(JToken token, string name, TreeNodeCollection parent)
    {
        if (token is JValue)
        {
            parent.Add(new TreeNode(string.Format("{0}: {1}", name, ((JValue)token).Value)));
        }
        else if (token is JArray)
        {
            AddArrayNodes((JArray)token, name, parent);
        }
        else if (token is JObject)
        {
            AddObjectNodes((JObject)token, name, parent);
        }
    }
    private static void AddArrayNodes(JArray array, string name, TreeNodeCollection parent)
    {
        var node = new TreeNode(name);
        parent.Add(node);

        for (var i = 0; i < array.Count; i++)
        {
        AddTokenNodes(array[i], string.Format("[{0}]", i), node.Nodes);
        }
    }



var @object = JObject.Parse(json);
        AddObjectNodes(@object, "JSON", treeView.Nodes);
```

my problem is i am getting output like this

[image]

I want the below list format. How do I handle JSON to get this data in [C#](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29) [Windows Forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms)?

I am using Newtonsoft [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm). Is there a way to break it into an arraylist?

```
---Work requestname ( Story mapping)
---Work requestname ( Story mapping)
---Work requestname ( Issue Collector)
---Work requestname ( Issue Collector)
```

And so on for a different work request

I am having a hard time generating a class for my JSON content. All online class generators generate a class for each project like I have project1, project2, and so on since my REST API will provide multiple projects and cannot create a class each time on the go.

[This guy has his class sorted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22191167/convert-json-string-to-c-sharp-object-list).

Comment: Generally you want to avoid naming variables and parameters `object` or `array` as apart from running into _reserved word_ naming conflicts, such names aren't very informative

Comment: Dynamic means the format change. Changing value  is  a normal behavior. Why not having a list <customObject> instead of an array list? [MSDN on don't use ArrayList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=netcore-3.1#remarks). And the whole code will just be a class definition and one line deserialization.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Json String to C# Object List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22191167/convert-json-string-to-c-sharp-object-list)

Comment: i am having hard time generating class for my json all online class generators generate class for each project like i have project1 , project2 & so on since my restapi will provide multiple projects cannot create class each time on the go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Newtonsoft.Json.Linq to deserialize the original JSON content then deserialize your projects (with dynamic names I assume). You can go over each of the projects and display the `ProjectObject` that contains your names and URLs.

```
public class ProjectObject
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("url")]
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

And use the following in your main to deserialize JSON content and go over each project (project1, project2, projectn).

```
var jobj = JObject.Parse(json);
foreach(var prop in jobj.Properties())
{
    // prop.Name is the name of the project you are iterating over.
    var project = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ProjectObject>>(jobj[prop.Name].ToString());
}
```

---

**UPDATED ANSWER**

You can use the following classes to deserialize the new JSON content you posted.

```
public class Class1
{
    [JsonProperty("projectCode")]
    public string ProjectCode { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("workRequests")]
    public List<Workrequest> WorkRequests { get; set; }
}

public class Workrequest
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Pame")]
    public string Project { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("url")]
    public string Url { get; set; }
}

// And in your main, or other function, you can access your items via for loop or foreach. Ex to print all requests,
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Class1>>(json);
obj.ForEach(item => item.WorkRequests.ForEach(request => Console.WriteLine($"---Work {request.Name} ( {item.Name} )")));
```

Comment: hi i am new to this json thing 
i have diffrent json now with actual data 
wil you help me generate and loop through it?? my expected output is same as mentioned in question just my json has been changed and this is the final one. i am updating json in Question

Comment: i am able to parse my json in JArray

Comment: @Dandy you changed the question altogether. This json doesnt have project1 project2 and so on. This new json has a standard format with different values of course. Not sure whats "dynamic" about it

Comment: dude thanks a lot  it worked,, about json i know, as soon as i got updated requirement i changed question but thanks again

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var property in @object.Properties())
{
     AddTokenNodes(property.Value, property.Name, node.Nodes);
}
```

Property.Name is the name of the **property**, not the value of the name attribute.

Try

```
AddTokenNodes(property.Value, property.Value.name, node.Nodes);
```

instead.

> I am having a hard time generating a class for my JSON content. All online class generators generate a class for each project like I have project1, project2, and so on since my REST API will provide multiple projects and cannot create a class each time on the go.

You don’t need to create a new class every time. that's what the dynamic Newtonsoft JSON classes are for.