# How to get result from Cypher Query in json using Neo4j C# Client

Tags: json, neo4j, json.net, neo4jclient

i am using Neo4j 2.0.3 DB and using C# client to access neodb. I could not find any way by which after querying db i can get results in the form of Json.
Please give me some links or examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get Cypher Query results in JSON format

eg. Consider a graph with person nodes and nodes have property personId. The below query will give you result in the form of json object.

```
MATCH (n:PERSON)-[:friend]->(friend:PERSON) RETURN {personId: n.personId, friends: collect(distinct friend.personId)} as PersonData
```

Now you have the json string. Now using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611031/convert-json-string-to-c-sharp-object) or anyother way you can get it in an object

Comment: I have this code can you tell me how can i get json from this data dirctly without using json serializer using c#. client.Cypher.Match("(user:User)-[:WATCHES]->(programme:Programme)").Return((user, programme) => new { UserInfo = user.As<UserInfo>(), Programme = programme.As<Programme>() }).Results;

Comment: Why dont you try executing it as a whole cypher query instead of using Cypher.Match etc... You can form a cypher query and just run it and iterate through the result..