# How Can I get JSON from Neo4j using Neo4j.Driver

Tags: c#, json, neo4j, cypher

I use the `Neo4j.Driver` nuget package, and I want my result as a JSON object.

When I use The Neo4j Console, I can see the result in JSON format. And I can  build a Cyper query which returns in it, But How Can I get in C#? Here is the Query:

```
 MATCH (p:Person) 
 WHERE p.PersonId = '12345'
RETURN p AS PersonData
```

It works well, but when I use this command in `session.Run()` the return value is a `IStatementResult` which is contains `IRecord` or list of `IRecord`.

I Can read all element from record like this:

```
string id = record["PersonId"];
string name = record["Name"];
```

But I want it in JSON :)

```
 string jsonData = MagicFunction_WhichReturn_WithJSON( record );
```

It must be possible, beacuse some post are write about it like [this](https://community.neo4j.com/t/query-neo4j-to-return-json-data-using-the-c-driver/1961) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24751399/how-to-get-result-from-cypher-query-in-json-using-neo4j-c-sharp-client). Just a mechanism is not described.

I feel it must be very simple solution, Just I did not found it :(

Answer (score 0):

You could use a JSON serializer/deserializer library such as `Newtosoft.Json`, or the native `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer` class, using it as

```
string jsonData = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(record)
```

or

```
string jsonData = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(record)
```