# ajax function not returning data in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to create cross domain ajax script but I am little struggling as to why the ajax function **is outputting** `undefined` in the table id, instead of correct dynamic data.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $.support.cors = true;
    $.ajax({
        type: "Post",
        crossDomain: true,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "http://localhost:27335/test2.aspx/BindDatatable",
        data: "{}",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data)
            for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
                $("#tbDetails").append("<tr><td>" + data.d[i].Name+ "</td><td>" + data.d[i].Loan + "</td><td>" + data.d[i].Evnt + "</td></tr>");
            }
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: _in the table id_ what ID are we talking about? and what's the output of `console.log(data)`

Comment: Have you debugged it using Firebug to see what (if anything) is being returned from the ajax request?

Comment: `dataType: "jsonp",` isn't it be there instead?

Comment: What is the content of the `data` argument?

Comment: I have debugged it in Firebug many times, but I am unable to see the data parameter in the response header of the ajax call.  I tried changing the `datatype:jsonp`, but this returns null data -(but the request is 200 response).

Comment: What do you see when you load the URL directly in the browser?

Comment: I have attached my current output in my original post, also including the additional code in my server side, for further reference. Thank you for any further assistance.

Comment: This is the table id, i am passing the ajax function into `<table id="tbDetails" width="580px" height="auto" class="gridtable">`. thanks

Comment: What is the console-output of `console.log(data)`?

Comment: apology for the late reply. There are currently no errors or data shown in the console log (chrome firebug). Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow below steps

1.Debug your method BindDatatable()

2.In `return serializer.Serialize(details);` You got any result or not ?

3. If yes then write below line in your code.

if not then serialized with different serializer e.g. Newtonsoft. you can found more details here [Convert JSON String To C# Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611031/convert-json-string-to-c-sharp-object/28061912#28061912)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.support.cors = true;
    $.ajax({
        type: "Post",
        crossDomain: true,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "http://localhost:27335/test2.aspx/BindDatatable",
        data: "{}",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data.toSource()) ; 
            console.log(data);
            for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
                $("#tbDetails").append("<tr><td>" + data.d[i].Name+ "</td><td>" + data.d[i].Loan + "</td><td>" + data.d[i].Evnt + "</td></tr>");
            }
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
});
```

This line **alert(data.toSource())**

4. IF you got any json then verify your json in [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com). if it is verified then make sure it is valid as per requirements and also parse.

```js
var parsedData = $.parseJSON(data);
```

5. It will work.

Comment: Thank you very much for thorough explanation.  my server code is returning data, but the json data format in jsonlint is failing the output string. So, I am currently figuring this out.  Thanks.

Comment: always welcome. Jsonlint is your validator of json and it is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You Webmethod **BindDatatable()** is returning you a JSON formatted data.
You need to parse it before using.

You can do it like as below:

Your Ajax post would be like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "Post",
    crossDomain: true,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "http://localhost:27335/test2.aspx/BindDatatable",
    data: "{}",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data)
        var parsedData=$.parseJSON(data);
        for (var i = 0; i < parsedData.d.length; i++) {
            $("#tbDetails").append("<tr><td>" + parsedData.d[i].Name+ "</td><td>" + parsedData.d[i].Loan + "</td><td>" + parsedData.d[i].Evnt + "</td></tr>");
        }
    },
    error: function (result) {
        alert("Error");
    }
});
```

Here I have made use on **parsedData**. Instead of the **data**.
You can have a look..

Hope this helps!!