# Deserialize RestResponse to JSON data

Tags: c#, json.net

how to deserialize the below Rest response to JSON response
my rest response is in the format

```
{
"new_token":"fdffdsfdsfdsf",
"expires_in":400,
"login_type":"abc"
}
```

I have a POCO class as

```
public string NewToken { get; set; }
public string ExpiresIn { get; set; }
public string LoginType { get; set; }
```

How to store the rest response into the POCO classs

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert JSON String To C# Object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611031/convert-json-string-to-c-sharp-object)

Comment: What have you attempted? This should be easy with JSON.NET, there are many existing resources describing how to do this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to deserialise the JSON into your class.

Assuming your class is called `Foo`, just use the `JavaScriptSerializer` object:

```
Foo result = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Foo>(json);
```

You will need to add a reference to `System.Web.Extensions` in order to access the `JavaScriptSerializer`.

**EDIT**

Following additional clarification regarding the mapping of the raw JSON property names to nice-looking .Net names, and assuming your class is called `POCO`, I suggest using the `DataContractJsonSerializer` as follows:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.Text;

[DataContract()]
class POCO
{
    [DataMember(Name = "new_token")]
    public string NewToken { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "expires_in")]
    public string ExpiresIn { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "login_type")]
    public string LoginType { get; set; }
}

class SomeClass
{
    void DoSomething(string json)
    {
        MemoryStream reader;
        POCO output;
        DataContractJsonSerializer serializer;

        reader = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json));
        serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(POCO));
        output = serializer.ReadObject(reader) as POCO;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks martin, but I need in c#

Comment: I tried adding reference for `System.Web.Extensions` but it fails.  my project is targeting `.Net4.5`

Comment: Is your project targeting `.Net 4.5` or `.Net 4.5 the Client Profile`?  This code works perfectly in `.Net 4.5`, but the assembly will be unavailable in the `Client Profile`.

Comment: project targeting `.Net4.5` martin. Not `.Net4.5 client Profile`. Its really strange, that why its not working

Comment: When you say that adding the reference to `System.Web.Extensions` fails, what happens when you attempt to add it?

Comment: finally added it now by reference `System.Web.Script.Serialization`. But after execution the values are null stored in the POCO. The rest response are in format `new_token` but the members in class are `NewToken`. Is that so the values are not deserialized.

Comment: It works, when I rename the variable as `new_token` instead `NewToken`. But we cant name a POCO class member in lowercase and with underscores

Comment: @madhu I've updated the answer with a new edit involving `DataContractJsonSerializer`, which offers the ability to map Json property names to .Net properties using the `DataMember` attribute.

Comment: Thanks martin. I m trying to implement the same

Comment: martin, sorry for bothering you again dude, I m getting the below error message during deserilization `{"Expecting element 'root' from namespace ''.. Encountered 'None'  with name '', namespace ''. "}`. My code is `MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream {Position = 0};
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms);
            TokenResponse r = (TokenResponse) ser.ReadObject(ms);`

Comment: ignore me, I fixed it