# Convert JSON array to a c# object collection

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I've a JSON like below,

```
[
  {
    "document":
            {
                "createdDate":1476996267864,
                "processedDate":1476996267864,
                "taxYear":"2015",
                "type":"user_document"
            }
    },
  {
     "document":
            {
                "createdDate":1476998303463,
                "processedDate":0,
                "taxYear":"2015",
                "type":"user_document"
            }
    }
  ]
```

I need to convert it into a c# object. My object type is as below-

```
public class UserDocument
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "type")]
        public string type { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "taxYear")]
        public string taxYear { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "createdDate")]
        public string createdDate { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "processedDate")]
        public string processedDate { get; set; }

    }
```

I'm using below code to deserialize the json but all UserDocument properties are null

```
 var test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<UserDocument>>(jsonString);
```

Why am I getting all UserDocument properties are null, what's wrong here? I'm not getting any error.

Also can you suggest a good example in getting CouchBase queryresult into a .net object.

Comment: `processedDate` and `createdDate` are not strings.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611031/convert-json-string-to-c-sharp-object

Comment: your json is wrong

Comment: @RhinoDevel - I've corrected the type problem, still I've the same null issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems your json is not in correct format. If I say your json is like

```
[
    "document":
            {
                "createdDate":1476996267864,
                "processedDate":1476996267864,
                "taxYear":"2015",
                "type":"user_document"
            },

     "document":
            {
                "createdDate":1476998303463,
                "processedDate":0,
                "taxYear":"2015",
                "type":"user_document"
            }
  ]
```

Then create a model like

```
public class Document
{
   public UserDocument document {get;set;}
}
```

and change your `UserDocument` model's `createdDate` and `processedDate` properties as `double` because its like that in your json

```
public class UserDocument
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "type")]
        public string type { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "taxYear")]
        public string taxYear { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "createdDate")]
        public double createdDate { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "processedDate")]
        public double processedDate { get; set; }

    }
```

and then deserialize

```
var test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Document>>(jsonString);
```

Comment: You could also add properties to your `UserDocument` class that return the `createdDate` and `processedDate` properties as `DateTime` values.

Comment: @krillgar those are not actual datetime type they are utc double value of equivalent datetiem

Comment: @Mostafiz Ticks? You can have a property like `public DateTime TaxYear => new DateTime(taxYear);`

Comment: yeah good one, thanks :) but I think double is enough for OP's purpose

Answer (score 1):

Something like this  (using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq):

`var documents  = JArray.Parse(json).Select(t => t["document"].ToObject<UserDocument>());`