# Parsing and validating JSON string in C#

Tags: c#, json, api, parsing

I am working on a side project at work (I'm not a developer).

What I'm trying to achieve is validating whether `status`is `NULL` or it has `ERR` in the login request response so I can know if I may continue the process.

This is the code I have so far:

```
namespace EseyeSIMAPI
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var client = new RestClient("https://siam.eseye.com/Japi/Tigrillo");
        var loginRequest = new RestRequest("/login/", Method.POST);

        loginRequest.AddHeader("postman-token", "4e67ed4c-4130-4067-9539-d5ed6b6ad761");
        loginRequest.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
        loginRequest.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        loginRequest.AddParameter("application/json", "{\r\n\"username\" : \"someusername\" ,\r\n\"password\" : \"somepassword\" ,\r\n\"portfolioID\" : \"someportfolioid\"\r\n}", ParameterType.RequestBody);

        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(loginRequest);

        client.ExecuteAsync(loginRequest, x =>
        {
            var json = x.Content;
        });

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
public class LoginStatus
{
    public Status status { get; set; }
    public string cookie { get; set; }
    public string permissions { get; set; }
    public string canActivate { get; set; }
}

public class Status
{
    public string errorCode { get; set; }
    public string errorMessage { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
}
}
```

I receive the following JSON response:

```
{
"status": {
"errorCode": "",
"errorMessage": "",
"status": "OK"
},
"cookie": "2p255ju6q1lfql594uppnq9lp2",
"permissions": "ULE",
"canActivate": "yes"
}
```

So I created a class that will handle all the response parameters in the JSON object. I'm just not sure how exactly to access `status`.

Comment: So you want to de-serialise `x.Conent` to `LoginStatus` is that correct?

Comment: If so, then [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611031/convert-json-string-to-c-sharp-object) seems to have a suitable answer

Comment: @musefan yep. I want to be able to access each key-value pair.

Comment: If you have an alternate solution that solves your problem, post that as a new answer. Don't edit the question to include the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following on from my comments, this is how you would specifically do it with your code using the [JavaScriptSerializer class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
client.ExecuteAsync(loginRequest, x =>
{
    var json = x.Content;

    JavaScriptSerializer jsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    LoginStatus loginStatus = jsonSerializer.Deserialize<LoginStatus>(json);

    string errorCode = loginStatus.status.errorCode;
});
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]' to type 'EseyeSIMAPI.LoginStatus'.

Comment: @KobbiGal: Sorry, I don't have ability to test at the minute. Can you try my updated answer

Comment: Error CS0308 The non-generic method 'JavaScriptSerializer.DeserializeObject(string)' cannot be used with type arguments

Comment: @KobbiGal: OK, I fixed it now. And tested it this time too. It definitely works now.

Comment: How come when I enter wrong credentials, printing the errorcode still returns nothing? (it's supposed to return E0000)

Comment: @KobbiGal: No idea, that's all down to your authentication method. I assume it's not in the `x.Content` is it?