# extracting data from big JSON

Tags: c#, json, json.net

We have a very big JSON, close to 1500 fields. We want to read most of the JSON fields (Most of the time I have to read whole JSON and get 80% of data). What could be the most performance optimized way ? should we use JObject.Parse and then use JsonPath or  should we use JsonConvert.DeserializeObject and then use linq queries or are there any other better ways

Comment: It looks like you are already aware of a few options, why won't you just try them and measure time using stopwatch to find the most performant way?

Comment: May be this link will be helpful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611031/convert-json-string-to-c-sharp-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned it's a big JSON, I will suggest you to use a stram reader so you don't need to load the whole JSON into memory

```
    using (var reader = new JsonTextReader(new StreamReader(stream)))
    {
        while(!(reader.TokenType.Equals(JsonToken.EndObject) && reader.Depth == 0))
        {
            if (reader.TokenType.Equals(JsonToken.PropertyName))  
                 if (!DoSomething(reader))
                    break;
            if (!reader.Read())
                break;
        }
    }
```

In your `DoingSomething` method, you can for example, read value from one field

```
    private bool DoSomething(JsonTextReader reader)
    {
        if(reader.Path.Equals("FieldName_You_Are_Looking_For"))
        {
            string jsonText = JsonTextReaderToJsonText(reader);
            // Do something to read the value
        }
        // return true to continue reading, return false to stop reading
        return true;
    }
```

Hope it can help you

Comment: Thanks Jianping Liu, Most of the time I have to read whole JSON and get 80% of data

Comment: memory wise, stream reader is more efficient than loading entire data into memory.

Comment: The only limitation i see that i need to add so many If conditions for checking each path any better way for path checking and retrieving