# Incorrect Format for JSON deserialization

Tags: c#, json, json.net, restsharp

I am very much out of my element on this. In C# I am writing a method to get data back from a website using REST. Per the documentation on the website I should use something like this:

```
var client = new RestClient(url + "token");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                "grant_type=password&username=" + UserName +
                "&password=" + Password +
                "&tenant=" + Company,
                ParameterType.RequestBody);

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

to get a response that looks like this:

```
{
  "access_token": "generated_token_value",
  "token_type": "bearer",
  "expires_in": 2591999
}
```

However, I have no earthly clue to how to read that info. I'm assuming that the JSON response is in my "response" variable, but beyond that I'm at a loss. I've done a little digging and have found Json.NET should be helpful, but it's over my head. Their documentation suggests:

```
Product deserializedProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(output);
```

However if I convert that into something that looks correct for mine (creating a "Responses" Class and then):

```
Responses responses = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Responses>(response);
```

I get an error in VS under the "response" saying "cannot convert from 'RestSharp.IRestResponse' to 'string'.

I feel like I just need a little nudge to get over this hump.

Comment: What does your `Responses` class look like?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert JSON String To C# Object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611031/convert-json-string-to-c-sharp-object)

Comment: Use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Responses>(response.Content);`

Comment: @Liam he's not having JSON String but `IRestResponse` object meaning it's not a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to the repository of [`RestSharp`](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/RestSharp/IRestResponse.cs#L38) you'll see that it has special property called `Content` which contains JSon in a string format.

Now you can use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Responses>(response.Content);` to retrieve your object.

Comment: That did the trick. the Content property did the trick. Now I've got some other work to do, but the key part works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
Responses responses = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Responses>(response.Content);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be declaring the response for the out type you're expecting

```
IRestResponse<Responses> response = client.Execute<Responses>(request);
```