# How to parse json key - value to object C# from Request.Properties["MS_QueryNameValuePairs"]

Tags: c#

I have string json as

```
"[{\"Key\":\"a\",\"Value\":\"1\"},{\"Key\":\"b\",\"Value\":\"2\"}}]"
```

I want parse to object

```
class abc{
public string a{get; set;}
public string b{get; set;}
}
```

Please, help me

Comment: do you get some error, or something? I hope you tried to find solution by yourself, right :) 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611031/convert-json-string-to-c-sharp-object

Comment: Why are 2K+ rep users answering this obvious duplicate? Read [answer].

Comment: No, json string as key-value pair. I want convert key-value pair to object class

Comment: @CodeCaster: That isn't quite an exact dupe - there may be one out there that is but in this case the complexity is that rather than having json like `{Propety: Value}` it is `{Key: "propertyname", Value: "Value"}` which is a harder question.

Answer (score 1):

you have  to  [Newtonsoft Library](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) 
and use

```
var dict=  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,int>>("[{\"Key\":\"a\",\"Value\":\"1\"},{\"Key\":\"b\",\"Value\":\"2\"}}]");
```

Comment: Additional information: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Int32]' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.

Answer (score 0):

[Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) is a Popular high-performance JSON framework for .NET

Install this nuget package then it's as simple as:

```
var json = "[{\"Key\":\"a\",\"Value\":\"1\"},{\"Key\":\"b\",\"Value\":\"2\"}}]";

var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<abc>>(json);
```

Comment: Will that actually cope with the format being Key/value attributes rather than the more usual `{a: Value}` type syntax? If I run the code I get null for `a` and `b`...

Comment: Yes. This' s format key/value

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about parsing to a defined object.
However you can use A .Net library called Newtonsoft
`JObject o = JObject.Parse(x.ToString());`

With JObject being an instance of Newtonsoft.JSON.Linq.JObject