# How to get single list item from response message in web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am new to web api. I have a method, that returns 3 objects from response message. I want to get specific object from the response message,

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetAllStudents(HttpReqestMessage request)
{
   HttpResponseMessage response = null;
   return CreateHttpResponse(request, () =>
   {
      // some logics here
      response = request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode = OK, new {success = true, StudentName, ListOfStudents, ListOfSubjects});

      return response;
   });
}
```

In this above code i want to get the ListOfStudents object alone from the response message. Please anyone help me to get this.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to get just that object here in this code?  Or in the code which calls this service?  If the latter, where is that code?  What format is the response?  How do you currently read that response?

Comment: This feels like an 
[XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What does `CreateHttpResponse` do? How are we suppose to know what it will return?

Comment: try this: `response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result` and you'll get a json string in return. Next try to deserialize the json string with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611031/convert-json-string-to-c-sharp-object

Comment: I guess you could use another `ReadAs...Async()`, but not sure which one.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a malformatted json , you should create a property for each list, check the next example :

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetAllStudents(HttpReqestMessage request)
{
   HttpResponseMessage response = null;
   return CreateHttpResponse(request, () =>
   {
      // some logics here
      response = request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode = OK, new {success = true, studentName = StudentName, listOfStudents = ListOfStudents, listOfSubjects =  ListOfSubjects});
      return response;
   });
}
```

Example getting this with with jquery

```
$.get("GetAllStudents", function(data) {
   if (data.success)
   {
      console.log(data.listOfStudents);
   }
});
```