# How would you model a json in c#

Tags: c#, json, oop, model

I have a JSON like

```
{
    "myObject":{
        "Difficult": true,
        "Impossible": false
    }
}
```

and a model like

```
public class Blas
{
    public string something { get; set; }
    public int somethinElse { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, bool> myObject{ get; set; } //this is how I'm currently modeling the JSON
}
```

and when I use it I'm doing `myObject["Difficult"];`
but I need to do something like `if(myObject.Difficult)..`

> Note to duplicate suggestion: The suggestion is
>   irrelevant because as the title says, my question is regarding to
>   model a JSON in C#, not converting. I can convert, but I need to
>   improve my current modeling in c#.

Comment: You need to parse your JSON into your model (or deserialize it to your model). Where from is the JSON coming into your C# code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert JSON String To C# Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611031/convert-json-string-to-c-sharp-object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add class "MyObject" like this

**Import**

```
using Newtonsoft.Json
```

**Code**

```
public class MyObject
{
    [JsonProperty("Difficult")]
    public bool Difficult { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Impossible")]
    public bool Impossible { get; set; }
}

public class MyData {
    [JsonProperty("myObject")]
    public MyObject { get; set; }
}
```

then, define class like this

```
MyData obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyData>(jsonString);
```

jsonString would be your json string.

Comment: I recently learned about interfaces, could I introduce an interface here or there? would it improve my code?

Comment: You can also remove the [JsonProperty] attributes if they are the same name and by convention it will auto map to that property.

Comment: @user33276346 I've always found it better to leave them in for clarity. Personal choice though.