# lambda expression join multiple tables with select and where clause

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, join

I have three table many to many relationship I have joined the three table and select the value I want but now I need to select one row from the query result by where by specifying the id  this is my three table [image]

And this is the query using `LINQ` lambda expression :

```
DataBaseContext db = new DataBaseContext();

public ActionResult Index()
{

    var UserInRole = db.UserProfiles.
        Join(db.UsersInRoles, u => u.UserId, uir => uir.UserId,
        (u, uir) => new { u, uir }).
        Join(db.Roles, r => r.uir.RoleId, ro => ro.RoleId, (r, ro) => new { r, ro })
        .Select(m => new AddUserToRole
        {
            UserName = m.r.u.UserName,
            RoleName = m.ro.RoleName
        });

    return View(UserInRole.ToList());
}
```

the result will be like that using `sql` query

`sql` query

```
select * 
from UserProfile u join webpages_UsersInRoles uir on u.UserId = uir.UserId 
                   join webpages_Roles r on uir.RoleId = r.RoleId
```

result of the `sql` query

[image]

now i use anther `sql` query to filter the result of previews `sql` query by where and set the condition to `where u.UserId = 1` to only give me back the user with the id 1 like that

```
select * 
from UserProfile u join webpages_UsersInRoles uir on u.UserId = uir.UserId 
                   join webpages_Roles r on uir.RoleId = r.RoleId 
where u.UserId = 1
```

and the result of this `sql` query

[image]

so how can i add the where `clause` to my lambda expression to give me the same result as the result of the `sql` query and thanks for any help

Comment: Kindly refer this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524813/convert-this-linq-expression-into-lambda

Answer (score 53, accepted):

If I understand your questions correctly, all you need to do is add the `.Where(m => m.r.u.UserId == 1)`:

```
var userInRole = db.UserProfiles.
    Join(db.UsersInRoles, u => u.UserId, uir => uir.UserId,
    (u, uir) => new { u, uir }).
    Join(db.Roles, r => r.uir.RoleId, ro => ro.RoleId, (r, ro) => new { r, ro })
    .Where(m => m.r.u.UserId == 1)
    .Select (m => new AddUserToRole
    {
        UserName = m.r.u.UserName,
        RoleName = m.ro.RoleName
    });
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: in this part 
`u => u.UserId, uir => uir.UserId`
**u.UserId** mean db.userProfiles.UserId ?

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for something and I found this post. I post this code that managed many-to-many relationships in case someone needs it.

```
var userInRole = db.UsersInRoles.Include(u => u.UserProfile).Include(u => u.Roles)
.Select (m => new 
{
    UserName = u.UserProfile.UserName,
    RoleName = u.Roles.RoleName
});
```