# Reactive Extensions - Equivalent LINQ expression as fluent expression

Tags: c#, linq, system.reactive

I have the following expression which groups stock quotes by symbol and returns an observable sequence of `PriceChange` objects reflecting the difference in price between two ticks of the same stock symbol:

```
return from q in quotes
       group q by q.Symbol into g
       from b in g.Buffer(2, 1)
       select new PriceChange() { Symbol = b[0].Symbol, Change = (b[1].Price - b[0].Price) / b[0].Price };
```

What I am trying to do is write the equivalent expression using LINQ fluent expressions. The closest I have come is this:

```
return quotes.GroupBy(q => q.Symbol)
             .Select(g => g.ToList()
                 .SelectMany(l => l)
                 .Buffer(2, 1)
                 .Do(b => Console.WriteLine(b[0].Symbol + "-" + b[1].Symbol))
                 .Select(b => new PriceChange())
              );
```

However this does not compile as the return type of that expression is `IObservable<IObservable<PriceChange>>` when what I need is just a `IObservable<PriceChange>`

If I try adding a `SelectMany` clause like this:

```
return quotes.GroupBy(q => q.Symbol)
             .Select(g => g.ToList()
                 .SelectMany(l => l)
                 .Buffer(2, 1)
                 .Do(b => Console.WriteLine(b[0].Symbol + "-" + b[1].Symbol))
                 .Select(b => new PriceChange())
              ).SelectMany(o => o);
```

it compiles but never produces any output.

What am I doing wrong here? How can I express this correctly using the fluent LINQ operators?

Comment: Try to use LINQpad to convert LINQ to Lambda expressions see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524813/convert-this-linq-expression-into-lambda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need:

```
return quotes
    .GroupBy(q => q.Symbol)
    .SelectMany(g => g.Buffer(2, 1).Select(b => new PriceChange {
        Symbol = b[0].Symbol,
        Change = (b[1].Price - b[0].Price) / b[0].Price
     })
    );
```