# How to convert LINQ query to Lambda automatically

Tags: linqpad

I am curious to know how to **convert LINQ query to lambda** so I visited the below link and follow the same but my linq query could not convert to lamda automatically.

[convert this LINQ expression into Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524813/convert-this-linq-expression-into-lambda)
[image]

This is my LINQ pad image where I use C# program:

[image]

Can anyone guide me what I am doing for which linq pad not being able to convert my linq to lambda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found out how to do it. here is the screen shot.

Writing the Query expression directly without `.ToList(), .FirstOrDefault(), SingleOrDefault()` will show the coresponding Lambda Expression in Lambda ExpressionTab.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps an explanation of how you solved your problem (in addition to the screenshot) would be useful?

Answer (score 2):

You're not in "C# Expression" mode. Copy and paste just the LINQ part (`from x in y...`) to a new tab (make sure C# Expression is selected from the droplist) and then try converting to lambda. Repeat for other LINQ query.

Comment: can u show me with picture. when i try a sample in C# expression mode then encounter error but when i test the same with C# statement then my program execute but lamda did not come.